# How do I display output of a python within Html in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying parse my blog posts with rss using feedparser and displaying it within the html tags. How i can display it within html ? Any help would be really appreciated.

I have tried it using it within the views.py and

```py
def gspace(request):
 d=feedparser.parse('http://glammingspace.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/defaultalt=rss')
    r = d.entries[0].summary
    response_html = '<br>'.join(r)
    return HttpResponse(response_html)
```

I have tried to display it in html , something like this

{{request.gspace}}

but it doesn't work fine .. help me to do it in better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to pass your blog posts to your template. For that, in Django, you can pass context variables to the template. So instead of simply returning an `HttpResponse`, try the following:

```
return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

Here, `template.html` is the HTML template file. The context would be a python dictionary which would contain posts.  And you can use `{{ context }}` in the template to access the same. Ideally, if you add each blog post as an item to the dictionary, you can iterate over the context dictionary using `{% for %}` loop.

Also, don't forget to import render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Comment: Thank's shahul .!